# Is it possible to set constraints for root view in XIB?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xib

Recently i was following a [tutorial](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/getting-started-with-reusable-frameworks-for-ios-development-f00d74827d11) to create frameworks in Swift, Where they create reusable visual effect view just like we see in Xcode build success pop up. I was doing the UI step by step where they created a new xib file and dragged and dropped `UIVisualEffectView` into it.

[image: Empty UIVisualEffectView without constraints]

In the above image we can see that the `UIVisualEffectView` doesn't contain any constraints. It only has auto resizing masks in size inspector(as expected).

---

But the following image from the tutorial suddenly contains all necessary constraints for it's root view.

[image: UIVisualEffectView with constraints]

I'm already aware that we CANNOT, by default set any constraints for the root view. But in the tutorial the author seems to have added constraints for the same. I'm just curious to know if it is possible to do that or am i missing any fundamental idea ?

**EDIT:**

Constraints for root view.

[image: UIAfterEffectView constraints]

Comment: The constraints are set on the *subview* of the root view.

Comment: Hmmm... actually, following that link, I don't see how he set the width and height constraints on the view. Maybe he was using an interim / beta Xcode?

Comment: Why the downvote? As per the edited question (last screenshot image), the constraints DO seem to belong to the `UIVisualEffectView`

Comment: I don't agree with the downvote at all. The question is well formulated and honestly and honorably posed. Indeed, to wonder what's going on in that screen shot seems quite insightful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, found one way to do this...

Haven't done any testing, so I'm not sure if the constraints are *really* set correctly or will be used by auto-layout at run-time, but this will put them there.

Create a new "View" XIB - this is how it looks to start:

[image]

Add a Visual Effect view to this view, and give it width and height constraints of 230 / 230:

[image]

Now, drag that Visual Effects view *out of the plain view, onto an empty space:

[image]

You will see it maintains its constraints. Then delete the original view, and add the other elements:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. I too did the same thing, but instead of dragging the subview, I made the `UIVisualEffectView` in Storyboard, added the constraints, and copy-pasted it into the XIB.

Answer (score 2):

As you can actually see on your screenshot the width/height constraints belong to the `View` (first subview of `Visual Effect View`).

Look at the green line:

[image]

Comment: That's what it looks like... but, as with the OP, I cannot set those constraints. Can you?

Comment: As of my examination with the xib in source code the height and width is set for the root view which is the visual effect view.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what's going on your tutorial (and I have no intention of watching it), and I have no idea under what circumstances the screen shot was achieved. But I do know the rules for how a view controller's main view gets sized.

Any view controller's *main view* must expect to be resized as it is placed into the interface. The size in the storyboard is therefore *meaningless*. That is why you cannot give it a size with auto layout.

If a view in a *xib* or storyboard is to be used as the *main view* of a view controller, it is meaningless (and would be wrong) to set constraints on it, because it will be the task of the view controller's *parent* (or, in the case of the window's `rootViewController`, of the window) to set the size of the view when it places it into the hierarchy.

If a view controller wants to vote on the size of its view when it is placed into the view hierarchy (for example, as a popover), that is what the content size (preferred explicit size) is for. But even then, the parent is the one who controls what actually happens.